How can I clear cache when I open my app if cache isn't empty in java?
I want to clear my app's cache when every time my app opens (something like in the onCreate) by checking if the cache directory is not empty. Is there any method to check if the cache is not empty, and then delete?

Why check if the cache is empty? Just empty it. If it's already empty nothing will happen.

You don't need to check if the cache is empty. If its already empty, nothing will happen. Here is a simple function to delete all subdirectories and files:
public static void deleteFilesFrom(String path) {
    File dir = new File(path);
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        if (files != null) {
            for (File file : files) {
                deleteRecursive(file);
            }
        }
    }
}
public static void deleteRecursive(File file) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        File[] files = file.listFiles();
        if (files != null) {
            for (File child : files) {
                deleteRecursive(child);
            }
        }
    }
    file.delete();
}

Declare them inside onCreate
    String cacheDirPath = getCacheDir().getPath();
    deleteCacheDirContents(cacheDirPath);


Thank you sir for your answer, May I know further, do I need to have the permissions required to run the above code?

No Need to call me sir. I am not that old
Anyways, You do need storage permissions to delete cache. Specifically speaking, you need "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"  permission. Add it in AndroidManifest and request the permission in onCreate.

@Agasthi it's mentioned in a comment in the linked duplicate. Short answer: no.

@Sohan you sure about that? The documentation for getCacheDir()says "Apps require no extra permissions to read or write to the returned path, since this path lives in their private storage."

@FedericoklezCulloca Hello sir, I ran the above code itself, it did not clear my app cache, so I added these two permissions 
 Then it cleared my cache, I assume this piece of code requires permissions

Anyway Thank you @Sohan again, you saved my day,  You deserved to be called sir, You taught me today about something I did not know.
